Does Iran make its own engines for its helicopters?
Iranian companies have 'cloned' some Western helicopter models but also made their own, more recently. Do they have the domestic capability to make engines for them though, or are these imported, if so from where? (E.g. Shaded drone engines were imported from Europe and then from China.)
N.B. In 2019, Gen. Bagheri said Iran was "on the verge" of making its own engines, but I guess that means they don't/didn't quite make them themselves though.

Apparently, yes.
Aero Engines Design and Manufacturing Company

An Iran-based company that specializes in building air-breathing engines for airplanes, helicopters, and drones; a subsidiary of the Iran Aviation Industries Organization (IAIO), a state-owned enterprise subordinate to the Iranian Ministry of Defense and Armed Forces Logistics (MODAFL); according to the U.S. Department of the Treasury, a front company that has carried out covert procurement activities for Iran Aircraft Manufacturing Industries (HESA).

